# PowerPoint slides from Excel

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I need to create a visual in PowerPoint in a single slide from the data in excel. I am not asking here as how to import data in powerpoint. The data I have is related to project and it’s release dates. I can represent the slides in charts but it’s not good. I can manually design the above with good and stunning and simple visuals in PowerPoint but it’s tedious as the data is updated each month. I tried Gantt charts but the data is represented something like a stacked bar. I need to represent data with different and stunning simple ppt slides that’s easy to interpret other than chart format types.

How can I achieve this? Any lead would be of great help?

Answer (score 1):

Can you generate the beautiful diagrams in Excel? If yes, insert the Excel file in PowerPoint as OLE object, showing the graphic. Occasionally (when needed), open the file (double-click), update the values and graphics, close. You are ready again.

Comment: In excel, my requirement is not to use charts.In excel, the data entered is not formula based too. It's a random and uncategoized data. I can do the same by manually drawing the slides and good visuals in powerpoint but the biggest disadvantage to this approach is everytime when data is changed, I need to manually change all the values in the visuals. I tried Gantt chart but it's not visually appealing.